# Clearing text fields of other class

Tags: java, javafx

In my main class I'm having a mask with two textfields, that are defined as the following:

```
private TextField one;
private TextField two;
```

In the same class I have button that to clear those fields :

```
public void newButton() {
    one.clear();
    two.clear();
}
```

So far, this all works as expected.

I do however have a separat class for my root layout. This class contains a menu bar. I would like to also have the ability to clear my text fields by calling a function from a menu bar item.

I tried:

```
private void newMenu() {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.newButton();
}
```

This however is throwing me a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Do I miss something here?

Comment: When the newButton() method is called objects one and two are null.
Do you have a constructor for them?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't instantiate the `one` and `two` TextFields inside the constructor of Main class and instantiate the object inside other method, you will get this error. Check if the objects are null:

```
public void newButton() {
    if (one != null)
        one.clear();
    if (two != null)
        two.clear();
}
```

If you don't instantiate the textfields elsewhere, you need to add those lines inside the Main class constructor:

```
 Main(){
   ...
   one = new TextField();
   two = new TextField();
   ...
}
```